# Creating JavaScript global objects in awesomium

Tags: c#, awesomium

I trying to ask at Awesomium chat but dont get ansver.
So. Lets try this code:

```
JSObject jso1 = webView.CreateGlobalJavascriptObject("Super1");
JSObject jso2 = webView.CreateGlobalJavascriptObject("Super2");
webView.ExecuteJavascript("Super2 = function() { return 555; }");
JSValue val = webView.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("Super2();");
```

if we trace it using debuger we can watch jso2 will not be created yet but jso1 will.
So, val 2 never sets to 555.

Lets try this one:

```
webView.CreateGlobalJavascriptObject("Super1");
JSObject jso2 = webView.CreateGlobalJavascriptObject("Super2");
webView.ExecuteJavascript("Super2 = function() { return 555; }");
JSValue val = webView.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("Super2();");
```

Super2 will be created but not be assigned to function. val will be undefined (not 555).

Against:

```
webView.CreateGlobalJavascriptObject("Super1");
webView.CreateGlobalJavascriptObject("Super2");
webView.ExecuteJavascript("Super2 = function() { return 555; }");
JSValue val = webView.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("Super2();");
```

works perfectly! this code creating two object and assign Super2 as function. val sets 555 after code executing.

So. Question is who is wrong? Possible me becouse i may not understand principle of awesomium engine. Or its a bug?

regards!

Comment: not near VS, but i think the problem is that you don't use the JS Object as it is defined, you should use the bind method on the jso2 object, than you can call it. the reason the third example works, is because you don't keep any track of the global objects, thus making them available for GC, and the Super2 method you defined is a function on the V8 window scope and not on the object you defined. you can test it using the debuger, but again, no VS here, so i might be way off.

Comment: But i have no time to learn awesomium. I have choise GeckoFX - its more "fat" but "transparent" and have the same methods i already worked (the same Ms WebBrowser).. But i what to try Chromium Embedded using C++. I think it will be more faster.